# Converting an .exe for PSP

Tags: conversion

I'm looking to convert an .exe to a format that will be playable on the Playstation Portable.

The application is Street Fighter X Mega Man http://capcom-unity.com/mega_man

The PSP is the Go model, though I'm not sure if that matters.

I would appreciate any help in this matter, even if someone could only point me in the direction of the things I would need to know to tackle this.

Edit: This is also my first post on Superuser, so if someone could tell me what additional information I should include, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. You can't just "convert" an executable program from one platform to another. The source code must be ported and compiled specifically for the target platform.